# What to do with conflict of CSS property hover?

Tags: css

We're using a bootstrap page that we found for a menu that's displayed at the left. Then I added a menu at the top. The page basically looks like this.

The issue is that the following CSS that's supposed to affect the top menu is also affecting the menu at the left:

```
nav > ul > li:hover {
     background-color: rgb(0,168,224);
}
```

This CSS is in a file `menu.css` that's supposed to be used exclusively by the top menu, but when I change the color, it changed both the top and left menu. It also occurs with other properties.

[image]

I tried adding `!important;` but that didn't do much.
I'm familiar with basic CSS, but this seems a little more complex.

What can I do so that any changes to `hover` (and any other properties) will only affect the top menu?

Comment: It sounds like you'll need to use a more specific selector https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: It would help to see your HTML as well in a [mcve]

Comment: Your CSS code is not specific enough, which is why both menus get targeted, you can make them more specific through the use of IDs or Classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to write your css a bit more specific in order to style to top navigation.
For example, you can add an id to the top menu:

```
<nav id="topmenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
        ....
    <ul>
</nav>
```

Your css should be this:

```
nav#topmenu > ul > li:hover {
    background-color: rgb(0,168,224);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add class to tags which you want to affect and style by class names instead of tags.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have multiple stylesheets they can override one another if using the same names/elements. So instead of using

> nav > ul > li:hover

You should make a class or id for your menus (optionally in menu.css)
So this could be for the upper menu:

```
.upperMenuLi:hover{
background-color: Yellow;
}
```

and for your side menu you could do the same, but with a different name, like;

```
.sideMenuLi:hover{
background-color: Grey;
}
```

The above code causes the top menu to have a yellow bg on hover, and the side menu to have a grey background on over.

so keep in mind:
By using  nav > ul > li:hover that style will be applied to ALL elements following that order.

Answer (score 0):

You want to limit the scope of you rules. `nav > ul > li:hover` selects a `hovered` `li` item that is a direct child of a `ul` which in it's case is a direct child of a `nav` element. The "problem" is this hierarchy is very common and might (and does) clash with other structures.

You have to create a selector which is uniqe. The easiest way, and IMO the most elegant way is to declare descriptive classes for this and select based on those.

For instance:

```css
.navigation {
}

.navigation__list,
.navigation__list-item {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.navigation__list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: spece-between;
  padding: 0;
}

.navigation__list-item {
  padding: 0 10px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navigation__list-item:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0,168,224);
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul class="navigation__list">
    <li class="navigation__list-item"><a href="#">Home</a>
    <li class="navigation__list-item navigation__list-item--active"><a href="#">About</a>
  </ul>
</nav>
```